# Launching R script with SSH terminal

Tags: r, linux, ssh

I would like to execute an R script on a linux server using SSH Secure shell version 3.2.9. I am succesfully connected to the server and the first line in the SSH terminal window is [myusername@servername ~]$.
The R script I want to execute is just a simple testscript called "testcript.R" and looks like:

```
y<-rep(1,5)
write.table(y, file = "test.csv", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = ";",
            dec = ".", row.names = FALSE,  col.names = FALSE)
```

The R script is located on the linux server with the following path: "/home/myusername/Documents/R_scripts/testscript.R"

I simply want the variable y to be put into an Excel file and the Excel file should be located in my folder on the linux server. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have R installed on the server and you have permission to run it, you should call:
`Rscript testscript.R`

Comment: When running the line you proposed I get the following message: "Fatal error: cannot open file 'testscript.R': No such file or directory". However, when I instead do: "Rscript /home/myusername/Documents/R_scripts/testscript.R" it seems to run without errors. However, I cannot find the excel file on the linux server.

Comment: When you specify the file in the script (`"test.csv"`), include the full path to the file. Otherwise, I believe it is looking in the current directory that you type the command.

Comment: After logging in you are probably in /home/myusername/ directory (you can verify it by calling `pwd`). The file has been created in R working directory, most likely: /home/myusername

Comment: It now works. In the R script I changed "test.csv" to "/home/myusername/Documents/R_scripts/test.csv" and used "Rscript testscript.R" in the SSH terminal window. Thanks @Nick Nimchuk.